# Get Azure premium storage account properties

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cloud-services

I am trying to get premium storage account (classic) properties using next method:

```
public ServiceProperties GetStorageAccountProperties(string accountName, string accountKey)
    {
        var connectionString = string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1};", accountName, accountKey);
        var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient bloblClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        return bloblClient.GetServiceProperties();
    }
```

But, it throws a StorageException:
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
The extended error information contains: Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid. (QueryParameterName=restype
QueryParameterValue=service)
This method works fine with other standard (classic) accounts.

Perhaps, it's because of the limitations of the premium storage account. But how can I use CloudBlobClient for work with this type of storage account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetServiceProperties` makes [`Get Blob Service Properties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452239.aspx) REST API call which is used to get `CORS` and `Storage Analytics` setting. As both `CORS` and `Storage Analytics` are not supported for `Premium` storage account, you're getting this error.

> But how can I use CloudBlobClient for work with this type of storage
>   account?

You can use `CloudBlobClient` for all supported operations on a Premium Storage Account. For example, you can create a reference for a `Blob Container` and create a container using that.

Comment: Now it is clear. I will use other available operations