# Azure storage : find if account is premium or not

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there a way to find out if an account is premium or not using either Azure Storage Java API or the Azure REST API ?

If I have a storage account name and key, is there a way to figure out the storage account type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the subscriptionId, please use the REST solution provided by @Thiago Custodio.

If you don't know the subscriptionId, please check my following workaround.

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521092/get-azure-premium-storage-account-properties), we know CORS and Storage Analytics are not supported for Premium storage account, so we can get the account type based on this.  If downloadServiceProperties method doesn’t throw exception, the account type is Standard. Otherwise, the account type is Premium. Code below is for your reference.

```
public string getAccountType(string accountName, string accountKey)
{
    string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=" + accountName + ";AccountKey=" + accountKey + ";";
    // Setup the cloud storage account.
    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString);
    // Create a blob service client
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();
    try
    {
        bloblClient.downloadServiceProperties();
        return "Standard";
    }
    catch(StorageException e)
    {
        return "Premium";
    }
}
```

Comment: I have been through the thread , but the solution requires to rely on MSFT to not add the said services to premium storage. Which I am not sure is the right way of doing this.

Comment: Account name and key are credential for accessing storage contents but not the storage account property itself.  We can only determine the account type according the differences between Standard storage and Premium storage. We also could find that Premium storage does not support block blobs. We could write code which upload some bytes to a blob, if any exceptions throw. The storage type would be Premium storage.

Comment: Makes sense, would be interesting to know if MSFT plans on adding the said services to premium storage.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrive this information inside sku.tier from the REST API:

REQUEST

```
GET /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}?api-version=2016-12-01
```

RESPONSE

```
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}",
    "name": "accountName",
    "location": "account geo region",
    "tags": {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key2": "value2"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/StorageAccount",
    "properties": {
        "provisioningState": "status",
        "encryption": {
                "services": {
                        "blob": {
                                "enabled": true,
                                "lastEnabledTime": dateTime}
                }
                "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
        }
        "primaryEndpoints": {
            "blob": "blob endpoint",
            "queue": "queue endpoint",
            "table": "table endpoint",
             "file": "file endpoint"
        },
        "primaryLocation": "primary geo region",
        "statusOfPrimary": "available|unavailable",
        "lastGeoFailoverTime": "dateTime",
        "secondaryLocation": "secondary geo region",
        "statusOfSecondary": "available|unavailable",
        "secondaryEndpoints": {
            "blob": "secondary blob endpoint",
            "queue": "secondary queue endpoint",
            "table": "secondary table endpoint",
        },
        "creationTime": "dateTime",
        "customDomain": {
                "name": "user domain”
         },
        "accessTier": "Cool|Hot"
    },
    "sku": {
            "name": "Standard_LRS|Standard_ZRS|Standard_GRS|Standard_RAGRS|Premium_LRS"
            "tier": "Standard|Premium"
    }
    "kind": "Storage|BlobStorage"
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/srp_json_get_storage_account_properties

Comment: This requires an permissions on the storage account.  I am looking more for a solution that just works with the Storage account name and key.